# How to use only a subset of variables in R using the lm function?

Tags: r, lm

If I have variable bob and I am seeing what effect variable joe has on bob, I have the following function:

model <- lm(bob ~ joe)

But what if I have a third variable tim. And I only want my model to only include the data in which tim=1. How do I do this? I was thinking something like:

model <- lm(bob ~ joe, tim=1)

That doesn't work. Sorry, I'm new to R.

Comment: Create a new dataframe that subsets your current data frame using logical indexing: `df[df$tim == 1]`.

Comment: if `tim` is a categorical variable fitting the model `lm(bob ~ joe:tim)` works as long as you are able to understand the resultant interaction terms.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to subset your data.

```
# some example data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(bob = rep(1, 10), joe = rep(2, 10), tim = round(runif(10))

# subset the data to where tim == 1
df1 <- df[df$tim == 1, ]

# build model
model <- lm(bob ~ joe, data = df1)
```

Alternatively, you can do the subsetting directly in lm.

```
# build model
model <- lm(bob ~ joe, data = df[df$tim == 1, ])
```

In case you with to include `tim` in the regression, you can add it using `+`.

```
# build model
model <- lm(bob ~ joe + tim, data = df1)
```